# Can't upload favicon

Tags: html, web, favicon

I can't upload favicon. In title space it shows me the code, not favicon.

```
<head>
    <title>
          <link rel="icon" href="g.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png"> 
    </title>
</head>
```

So why it doesn't show me the favicon? And favicons name is clearly g.png.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
<head>
    <title>
      <link rel="icon" href="g.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png"> 
    </title>
</head>
```

to this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="g.png"/>
</head>
```

Make sure that your image is in the same directory. `<title>My page</title>` is the text that gets displayed next to the favicon. In my example it would be "My page".